# What type of RoundingMode should I use?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
BigDecimal res = new BigDecimal(time.getMinute()).divide(new BigDecimal(60), 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

and I want the following results to occur:

> 55/60 = 0.9167
>   17/60 = 0.2833

I am wondering what type of rounding I should use for these results. At the moment I am using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` but I'm unsure whether this is the right mode to be using in order to get these results.

Comment: You should phrase your expected rounding behaviour in words and then see if it matches HALF_UP. FWIW, it should produce the two cases you mentioned (but you can test that). Unless you need to handle negative numbers, this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Did you try with different rounding modes and enough use cases to determine which one you want? That would be a lot quicker than waiting for an answer here, since we don't know what you want mathematically given just two examples.

Comment: Why do you need BigDecimal here anyway? You can round `double` as well.

Comment: Yes that is the right mode. or perhaps you want to give more sample input and expected output.

Comment: Though a bit unnecessary to use `BigDecimal` here, you are using the correct `RoundingMode` for your expectations; for more information please check; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: @Thilo do you mean `Double`? How would I round a primitive `double`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: You shouldn't even be rounding your number at all.  There is no reason throw away precision.  Just `time.getMinute() / 60.0` is perfectly adequate.  If you want to *display* a number with only four digits of decimal precision, you should use a NumberFormat or Formatter.